# What should I do about a question mired in no-longer relevant negative comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I made the tragic error of not marking something as community wiki that should have been. The question is now mired in comments about how I'm a rep whore, despite having no such intentions. While the question has been re-opened as a community wiki, users still vote up the no-longer relevant comments. Putting aside issues of my own embarrassment, I think the question's negative history has sterilized the question's ability to get the number and quality of answers it had the potential to receive, limiting its usefulness. Personally, I would prefer the question just be deleted, in all its fruitlessness, but it has, however, received too many answers to vote for deletion. What's the appropriate action?

On a broader level, is there any solution to large amounts of non or no-longer relevant commentary, flaming in particular?

Comment: I feel your pain. There ought to be some sort of reaping function for comments: we never need more than one comment saying "Should be community wiki."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet would be to flag your post for moderator attention and indicate that the comments are no longer relevant. If a moderator agrees, they will delete the comments.

Comment: Done and done.  This works! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could flag the question for 'moderator attention' and ask one of the moderators to fix things for you.